# Skype Lite on Android: The Never-Disappearing Notifications Problem

Tags: android-11, skype

I am having a problem with my Skype Lite notifications on Android 11 and would like to know if this is a common problem with Skype Lite on Xiaomi phones.

The notifications on the phone don't disappear even after I tap and go inside the app, and even when I have replied to the messages.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Thank you!